# Check if element is interactable in C# Selenium/ChromeDriver app?

Tags: c#, selenium, click

I have a C# Selenium app that uses the ChromeDriver/WebDriver NuGet package that supports Chrome 88.  My Chrome version is 88.0.4324.104.

Some of the web pages I am working with have more than one BUTTON element with the same **class** and and **tagName** so when I execute my **FindDomElement()** call using my desired **xpath**, I get back multiple matching elements.  Only *one* of the returned elements is **interactable** and the other ones are not.  Right now I try executing a "Click()" call on each element until I find the right one, catching the **ElementNotInteractableException** exception for the ones that fail.

Is there a way to ask Selenium if an element is interactable?

Please note, all the elements *are* **visible** and **enabled** and I already know how to check the status of those properties via C#.  They simply are *not* helpful in this case.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: *Only one of the returned elements is interactable* - how do you recognize that? In the code? What values are set differently between 2 buttons (interactable and non-interactable)?

Answer (score 0):

An extension method might be a better solution here. It would return `true` if the element was clicked, and return `false` if the element was not interactable.

```
public static class WebElementExtensions
{
    public static void TryClick(this IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            element.Click();

            return true;
        }
        catch (ElementNotInteractableException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it is just a simple test:

```
if (button.TryClick())
{
    // Button was clicked successfully
}
else
{
    // Button is not interactable
}
```